# Воспроизведение видео в активном слайде Swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper, swiper.js

У меня есть слайдер Swiper, в каждом слайде находится видео. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы в активном слайде автоматически воспроизводилось видео. Возможно ли это реализовать?